# Babel changes layout of LNCS paper

Tags: babel, lncs

I am using the [LNCS](https://www.springer.com/gp/computer-science/lncs) springer class in its newest version.

MWE1:

```
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}[2018/03/10]
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: MWE1 output]

MWE2:

```
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}[2018/03/10]
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Reproduce it by:

```
 docker run --rm -it -v "$(pwd):/home" danteev/texlive pdflatex paper-min.tex
```

Works on Linux and on PowerShell. System configuration: https://github.com/dante-ev/docker-texlive/blob/master/Dockerfile

```
*File List*
  llncs.cls    2018/03/10 v2.20 
LaTeX document class for Lecture Notes in Computer Science
article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
multicol.sty    2017/04/11 v1.8q multicolumn formatting (FMi)
aliascnt.sty    2009/09/08 v1.3 Alias counter (HO)
remreset.sty    
  babel.sty    2018/02/14 3.18 The Babel package
english.ldf    2017/06/06 v3.3r English support from the babel system
blindtext.sty    2012/01/06 V2.0 blindtext-Package
  xspace.sty    2014/10/28 v1.13 Space after command names (DPC,MH)
***********
```

On MiKTeX it also happens:

```
*File List*
  llncs.cls    2018/03/10 v2.20 
LaTeX document class for Lecture Notes in Computer Science
article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
multicol.sty    2018/04/20 v1.8s multicolumn formatting (FMi)
aliascnt.sty    2009/09/08 v1.3 Alias counter (HO)
remreset.sty    
  babel.sty    2018/06/05 3.22 The Babel package
bblopts.cfg    2005/09/08 v0.1 add Arabic and Farsi to "declared" options of b
abel
english.ldf    2017/06/06 v3.3r English support from the babel system
blindtext.sty    2012/01/06 V2.0 blindtext-Package
  xspace.sty    2014/10/28 v1.13 Space after command names (DPC,MH)
***********
```

Similar problems happen with German and French.

Comment: I added the similar patches for French and German. Please, don't invalidate existing answers. You should have first asked in a comment to my answer about German.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javier Bezos has nailed it and credit should be given to him.

Until Springer fixes the bug related to `\switcht@albion` that, by the way, can be seen with the simple

```
\documentclass{llncs}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}
X\selectlanguage{english}X
\end{document}
```

which prints “X`<several spaces>`X”, you can recursively patch the faulty macro once and for all:

```
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\def\recursivepatch{%
  \ifpatchable\switcht@albion{ \def}
    {%
     \patchcmd\switcht@albion{ \def}{\def}{}{}%
     \recursivepatch
    }
    {\undef\recursivepatch}%
}
\recursivepatch
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\maketitle

X\selectlanguage{english}X
\clearpage
X\selectlanguage{english}X

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively, prepend `\relax` to the macro and use `\xpatchcmd*` for doing all patches in one step.

```
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{regexpatch}

\makeatletter
\edef\switcht@albion{%
  \relax\unexpanded\expandafter{\switcht@albion}%
}
\xpatchcmd*{\switcht@albion}{ \def}{\def}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\switcht@albion}{\relax}{}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\maketitle

X\selectlanguage{english}X
\clearpage
X\selectlanguage{english}X

\end{document}
```

Actually the same problem happens for French and German. One has to repeat the patches also for those languages:

```
\makeatletter
\edef\switcht@albion{%
  \relax\unexpanded\expandafter{\switcht@albion}%
}
\xpatchcmd*{\switcht@albion}{ \def}{\def}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\switcht@albion}{\relax}{}{}{}
\edef\switcht@deutsch{%
  \relax\unexpanded\expandafter{\switcht@deutsch}%
}
\xpatchcmd*{\switcht@deutsch}{ \def}{\def}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\switcht@deutsch}{\relax}{}{}{}
\edef\switcht@francais{%
  \relax\unexpanded\expandafter{\switcht@francais}%
}
\xpatchcmd*{\switcht@francais}{ \def}{\def}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\switcht@francais}{\relax}{}{}{}
\makeatother
```

Comment: But you've provided a short solution :-).

Comment: Solution currently doesn't work, because of some latex updates breaking regexpatch. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/578518/9075 for details.

Comment: @koppor I promise an update in a few days.

Answer (score 6):

It's a bug in `llncs.cls`, namely, missing `%` at end of lines 79-114. which should be:

```
\def\switcht@albion{%
\def\abstractname{Abstract.}%
\def\ackname{Acknowledgement.}%
\def\andname{and}%
\def\lastandname{\unskip, and}%
\def\appendixname{Appendix}%
\def\chaptername{Chapter}%
\def\claimname{Claim}%
\def\conjecturename{Conjecture}%
\def\contentsname{Table of Contents}%
\def\corollaryname{Corollary}%
\def\definitionname{Definition}%
\def\examplename{Example}%
\def\exercisename{Exercise}%
\def\figurename{Fig.}%
\def\keywordname{{\bf Keywords:}}%
\def\indexname{Index}%
\def\lemmaname{Lemma}%
\def\contriblistname{List of Contributors}%
\def\listfigurename{List of Figures}%
\def\listtablename{List of Tables}%
\def\mailname{{\it Correspondence to\/}:}%
\def\noteaddname{Note added in proof}%
\def\notename{Note}%
\def\partname{Part}%
\def\problemname{Problem}%
\def\proofname{Proof}%
\def\propertyname{Property}%
\def\propositionname{Proposition}%
\def\questionname{Question}%
\def\remarkname{Remark}%
\def\seename{see}%
\def\solutionname{Solution}%
\def\subclassname{{\it Subject Classifications\/}:}%
\def\tablename{Table}%
\def\theoremname{Theorem}}
```

`babel` attempts to fix this kind of bug, but doesn't always succed (in this particular case because this macro is being added to `\extrasenglish`, not to `\captionsenglish`).

Also `\switcht@francais` and `\switcht@deutsch` have unprotected end-of-lines, although quite well concealed.

Comment: Although I also agree, `\switcht@deutsch` is correctly defined, it does not work with `ngerman`. I updated my question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

The bug has been fixed in `llncs.cls`, version 2.21.

Comment: Welcome! Wouldn't it be possible to upload the classes to CTAN? It would make it possible to help users in a better way than to chase after sites providing different versions?

Comment: Latest version is available at <https://www.springer.com/gp/computer-science/lncs/conference-proceedings-guidelines>

Comment: @egreg: Good idea! I have forwarded it to the LNCS editorial.

Comment: Thank you so much for the upload! This fixes the bug https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=31897 from 1999 of debian, because CC-BY 4.0 is a "DFSG-free license" - see https://wiki.debian.org/DFSGLicenses#Creative_Commons_Attribution_unported_.28CC-BY.29_v4.0.