# cdcalendar error : Undefined control sequence

Tags: tikz-pgf, xpatch, tikz-calendar

I'm trying to compile `cdcalendar` code download from: https://github.com/liantze/cdcalendar

I and using `texlive2020` and keep getting the errors shown in:

[image]

How can I begin to fix the errors ?

Thank you!

Comment: This seems similar to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/578518/regexpatchcmd-failing-with-latex2e-2020-10-01-patch-level-4-use-cs-replacemen, you could try the workaround posted there in a comment (restore `l3kernel` to an earlier version where the command was not yet fully deprecated) until `xpatch` is updated - if that is indeed the problem.

Comment: A fix to `regexpatch` will be submitted soon.