# Compilation error since upgrade to Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: ubuntu, compilation-error

I get an error when I try to compile my LaTeX script. I did not make any change to the script. The only thing new (I guess) is that I upgraded my OS from Ubuntu 20.04 to Ubuntu 21.10. Below is the error message (note there is also a warning).

```
error: line 13: File ended while scanning use of \__kernel_file_name_expand_loop:w.
error: : Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 13.
warning: : fixltx2e is not required with releases after 2015(fixltx2e) All fixes are now in the LaTeX kernel.
```

Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Many thanks for your help!

EDIT: The error is raised at line 13 (blank line). Line 12 is
`\documentclass[journal abbreviation, manuscript]{copernicus}`, and there are only comments above that line. The complete error message is:

```
copernicus.cls: error: line 1241: Undefined control sequence. \regexpatchcmd{\pr@m@s}{\'}{\cA\'}{}{}
copernicus.cls: error: line 1241: Undefined control sequence. \regexpatchcmd{\pr@m@s}{\'}{\cA\'}{}{}
copernicus.cls: error: line 1241: Undefined control sequence. \regexpatchcmd{\pr@m@s}{\'}{\cA\'}{}{}
copernicus.cls: error: line 1241: Undefined control sequence. \regexpatchcmd{\pr@m@s}{\'}{\cA\'}{}{}
copernicus.cls: error: line 1241: Too many }'s. \regexpatchcmd{\pr@m@s}{\'}{\cA\'}{}{}
copernicus.cls: error: line 1242: Undefined control sequence. \xapptocmd{\ttfamily}{\in@texttttrue}{}{}
copernicus.cls: error: line 1242: Undefined control sequence. \xapptocmd{\ttfamily}{\in@texttttrue}{}{}
copernicus.cls: error: line 1242: Undefined control sequence. \xapptocmd{\ttfamily}{\in@texttttrue}{}{}
copernicus.cls: error: line 1242: Undefined control sequence. \xapptocmd{\ttfamily}{\in@texttttrue}{}{}
copernicus.cls: error: line 1242: Undefined control sequence. \xapptocmd{\ttfamily}{\in@texttttrue}{}{}
copernicus.cls: error: line 1242: Illegal parameter number in definition of \l__exp_internal_tl. \xapptocmd{\ttfamily}{\in@texttttrue}{}{}
copernicus.cls: error: line 1242: Undefined control sequence. \xapptocmd{\ttfamily}{\in@texttttrue}{}{}
copernicus.cls: error: line 1242: Illegal parameter number in definition of \l__exp_internal_tl. \xapptocmd{\ttfamily}{\in@texttttrue}{}{}
copernicus.cls: error: line 1242: Undefined control sequence. \xapptocmd{\ttfamily}{\in@texttttrue}{}{}
copernicus.cls: error: line 1242: Undefined control sequence. \xapptocmd{\ttfamily}{\in@texttttrue}{}{}
copernicus.cls: error: line 1242: Undefined control sequence. \xapptocmd{\ttfamily}{\in@texttttrue}{}{}
copernicus.cls: error: line 1473: Undefined control sequence. \global\advance\c@authnum
copernicus.cls: error: line 1478: Illegal parameter number in definition of \l__exp_internal_tl. \def\@tempa{#1
copernicus.cls: error: line 1478: Undefined control sequence. ...ef\AB@note{\AB@thenote}\else\def\AB@note
copernicus.cls: error: line 1478: Illegal parameter number in definition of \l__exp_internal_tl. ...AB@note{\AB@thenote}\else\def\AB@note{#1
copernicus.cls: error: line 1479: Undefined control sequence. \setcounter{Maxaffil}{0}
copernicus.cls: error: line 1479: Undefined control sequence. \setcounter{Maxaffil}{0}
copernicus.cls: error: line 1479: Undefined control sequence. \setcounter{Maxaffil}{0}
copernicus.cls: error: line 1479: Undefined control sequence. \setcounter{Maxaffil}{0}
copernicus.cls: error: line 1480: Missing number, treated as zero. \ifnum\value{authors}
copernicus.cls: error: line 1480: Missing = inserted for \ifnum. \ifnum\value{authors}
copernicus.cls: error: line 1480: Missing number, treated as zero. \ifnum\value{authors}
copernicus.cls: error: line 1481: Missing number, treated as zero. ...dafter\gdef\csname @sep\number\c@authors
copernicus.cls: error: line 1481: Missing \endcsname inserted. ...dafter\gdef\csname @sep\number\c@authors
copernicus.cls: error: line 1481: Undefined control sequence. ...@sep\number\c@authors\endcsname{\Authsep
copernicus.cls: error: line 1483: Undefined control sequence. \addtocounter{authors}{1}
copernicus.cls: error: line 1483: Undefined control sequence. \addtocounter{authors}{1}
copernicus.cls: error: line 1483: Undefined control sequence. \addtocounter{authors}{1}
copernicus.cls: error: line 1483: Undefined control sequence. \addtocounter{authors}{1}
copernicus.cls: error: line 1485: Undefined control sequence. ...t\@unexpandable@protect \let\and\AB@pand
copernicus.cls: error: line 1486: Use of \@xfootnotemark doesn't match its definition. \def\thanks{\protect\thanks}
copernicus.cls: error: line 1486: Use of \__kernel_file_name_expand_space:w doesn't match its definition. \def\thanks{\protect\thanks}
template.tex:   error:   line 13: File ended while scanning use of \__kernel_file_name_expand_loop:w.
template.tex:   error:          : Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 13.
fixltx2e.sty: warning:          : fixltx2e is not required with releases after 2015(fixltx2e) All fixes are now in the LaTeX kernel.
```

EDIT 2: Please find below the .log file.

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2022.1.19)  25 JAN 2022 14:41
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**template.tex
(./template.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4
L3 programming layer <2021-01-09> xparse <2020-03-03> (./copernicus.cls
Document Class: copernicus 2021/12/08 9.39 Copernicus papers
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fixltx2e.sty
Package: fixltx2e 2016/12/29 v2.1a fixes to LaTeX (obsolete)
Applying: [2015/01/01] Old fixltx2e package on input line 46.


Package fixltx2e Warning: fixltx2e is not required with releases after 2015
(fixltx2e)                All fixes are now in the LaTeX kernel.
(fixltx2e)                See the latexrelease package for details.

Already applied: [0000/00/00] Old fixltx2e package on input line 53.
)
Additional configuration file copernicus.cfg used
(./copernicus.cfg) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fleqn.clo
File: fleqn.clo 2016/12/29 v1.2b Standard LaTeX option (flush left equations)
\mathindent=\skip47
Applying: [2015/01/01] Make \[ robust on input line 50.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 51.
Already applied: [0000/00/00] Make \[ robust on input line 62.
Applying: [2015/01/01] Make \] robust on input line 74.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 75.
Already applied: [0000/00/00] Make \] robust on input line 83.
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count177
\c@section=\count178
\c@subsection=\count179
\c@subsubsection=\count180
\c@paragraph=\count181
\c@subparagraph=\count182
\c@figure=\count183
\c@table=\count184
\abovecaptionskip=\skip48
\belowcaptionskip=\skip49
\bibindent=\dimen138
)
\bleed=\dimen139
\longtwo@top=\skip50
\longtwo@bottom=\skip51
\longtwo@box=\box47

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ulem/ulem.sty
\UL@box=\box48
\UL@hyphenbox=\box49
\UL@skip=\skip52
\UL@hook=\toks15
\UL@height=\dimen140
\UL@pe=\count185
\UL@pixel=\dimen141
\ULC@box=\box50
Package: ulem 2019/11/18
\ULdepth=\dimen142
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2020/08/10 v2.0s Standard LaTeX package
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty
Package: textcomp 2020/02/02 v2.0n Standard LaTeX package
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/upquote/upquote.sty
Package: upquote 2012/04/19 v1.3 upright-quote and grave-accent glyphs in verba
tim
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/regexpatch/regexpatch.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2021-01-09 L3 programming layer (loader) 

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2020-01-29 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count186
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box51
))
Package: regexpatch 2020/10/06 v0.2e Extending etoolbox patching commands

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
Package: xparse 2020-10-27 L3 Experimental document command parser

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse-generic.tex))
)
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \LaTeX3 error: 
                           Use \cs_replacement_spec:N not \token_get_replace...
l.1241 \regexpatchcmd{\pr@m@s}{\'}{\cA\'}{}{}
                                             
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \LaTeX3 error: 
                           Use \cs_prefix_spec:N not \token_get_prefix_spec:...
l.1241 \regexpatchcmd{\pr@m@s}{\'}{\cA\'}{}{}
                                             
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \LaTeX3 error: 
                           Use \cs_argument_spec:N not \token_get_arg_spec:N...
l.1241 \regexpatchcmd{\pr@m@s}{\'}{\cA\'}{}{}
                                             
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \LaTeX3 error: 
                           Use \cs_replacement_spec:N not \token_get_replace...
l.1241 \regexpatchcmd{\pr@m@s}{\'}{\cA\'}{}{}
                                             
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Too many }'s.
\l__exp_internal_tl ->\egroup 
                              \tex_def:D \xpatch_tmpa:w \egroup {\egroup }
l.1241 \regexpatchcmd{\pr@m@s}{\'}{\cA\'}{}{}
                                             
You've closed more groups than you opened.
Such booboos are generally harmless, so keep going.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \LaTeX3 error: 
                           Use \cs_replacement_spec:N not \token_get_replace...
l.1242 \xapptocmd{\ttfamily}{\in@texttttrue}{}{}
                                                
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \LaTeX3 error: 
                           Use \cs_prefix_spec:N not \token_get_prefix_spec:...
l.1242 \xapptocmd{\ttfamily}{\in@texttttrue}{}{}
                                                
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\expand@font@defaults ->\edef \rmdef@ult 
                                         {\rmdefault }\edef \sfdef@ult {\sfd...
l.1242 \xapptocmd{\ttfamily}{\in@texttttrue}{}{}
                                                
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\expand@font@defaults ...efault }\edef \sfdef@ult 
                                                  {\sfdefault }\edef \ttdef@...
l.1242 \xapptocmd{\ttfamily}{\in@texttttrue}{}{}
                                                
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\expand@font@defaults ...efault }\edef \ttdef@ult 
                                                  {\ttdefault }\series@maybe...
l.1242 \xapptocmd{\ttfamily}{\in@texttttrue}{}{}
                                                
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Illegal parameter number in definition of \l__exp_internal_tl.
<to be read again> 
                   1
l.1242 \xapptocmd{\ttfamily}{\in@texttttrue}{}{}
                                                
You meant to type ## instead of #, right?
Or maybe a } was forgotten somewhere earlier, and things
are all screwed up? I'm going to assume that you meant ##.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \bfdef@ult 
                      
l.1242 \xapptocmd{\ttfamily}{\in@texttttrue}{}{}
                                                
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Illegal parameter number in definition of \l__exp_internal_tl.
<to be read again> 
                   1
l.1242 \xapptocmd{\ttfamily}{\in@texttttrue}{}{}
                                                
You meant to type ## instead of #, right?
Or maybe a } was forgotten somewhere earlier, and things
are all screwed up? I'm going to assume that you meant ##.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \mddef@ult 
                      
l.1242 \xapptocmd{\ttfamily}{\in@texttttrue}{}{}
                                                
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\prepare@family@series@update ...get@series@value 
                                                  \@empty \def \target@meta@...
l.1242 \xapptocmd{\ttfamily}{\in@texttttrue}{}{}
                                                
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\prepare@family@series@update ...eta@family@value 
                                                  {#1}\expandafter \edef \cs...
l.1242 \xapptocmd{\ttfamily}{\in@texttttrue}{}{}
                                                
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
l.1473        \global\advance\c@authnum
                                       \@ne
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Illegal parameter number in definition of \l__exp_internal_tl.
<to be read again> 
                   1
l.1478        \def\@tempa{#1
                            }\ifx\@tempa\@empty\def\AB@note{\AB@thenote}\els...
You meant to type ## instead of #, right?
Or maybe a } was forgotten somewhere earlier, and things
are all screwed up? I'm going to assume that you meant ##.

! Undefined control sequence.
l.1478 ...ef\AB@note{\AB@thenote}\else\def\AB@note
                                                  {#1}%
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Illegal parameter number in definition of \l__exp_internal_tl.
<to be read again> 
                   1
l.1478 ...AB@note{\AB@thenote}\else\def\AB@note{#1
                                                  }%
You meant to type ## instead of #, right?
Or maybe a } was forgotten somewhere earlier, and things
are all screwed up? I'm going to assume that you meant ##.

! Undefined control sequence.
\GenericError  ...                                
                                                    #4  \errhelp \@err@     ...
l.1479         \setcounter{Maxaffil}{0}
                                       \fi
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\GenericError  ...                                
                                                  \let \@err@               ...
l.1479         \setcounter{Maxaffil}{0}
                                       \fi
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\GenericError  ...                                
                                                  \@empty \def \MessageBreak...
l.1479         \setcounter{Maxaffil}{0}
                                       \fi
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\GenericError  ...                                
                                                     \endgroup 
l.1479         \setcounter{Maxaffil}{0}
                                       \fi
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \c@authors 
l.1480       \ifnum\value{authors}
                                  >1\relax
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! Missing = inserted for \ifnum.
<to be read again> 
                   \c@authors 
l.1480       \ifnum\value{authors}
                                  >1\relax
I was expecting to see `<', `=', or `>'. Didn't.

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \c@authors 
l.1480       \ifnum\value{authors}
                                  >1\relax
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \c@authors 
l.1481 ...dafter\gdef\csname @sep\number\c@authors
                                                  \endcsname{\Authsep}%
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \c@authors 
l.1481 ...dafter\gdef\csname @sep\number\c@authors
                                                  \endcsname{\Authsep}%
The control sequence marked <to be read again> should
not appear between \csname and \endcsname.

! Undefined control sequence.
l.1481 ...@sep\number\c@authors\endcsname{\Authsep
                                                  }%
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\GenericError  ...                                
                                                    #4  \errhelp \@err@     ...
l.1483       \addtocounter{authors}{1}
                                      %
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\GenericError  ...                                
                                                  \let \@err@               ...
l.1483       \addtocounter{authors}{1}
                                      %
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\GenericError  ...                                
                                                  \@empty \def \MessageBreak...
l.1483       \addtocounter{authors}{1}
                                      %
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\GenericError  ...                                
                                                     \endgroup 
l.1483       \addtocounter{authors}{1}
                                      %
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
l.1485 ...t\@unexpandable@protect \let\and\AB@pand
                                                  
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Use of \@xfootnotemark doesn't match its definition.
<argument> ...ootnotemark \q__file_recursion_tail 
                                                  
l.1486           \def\thanks{\protect\thanks}
                                             \def\footnote{\protect\footnote}%
If you say, e.g., `\def\a1{...}', then you must always
put `1' after `\a', since control sequence names are
made up of letters only. The macro here has not been
followed by the required stuff, so I'm ignoring it.

! Use of \__kernel_file_name_expand_space:w doesn't match its definition.
\__kernel_file_name_expand_loop:w ...cursion_stop 
                                                  
l.1486           \def\thanks{\protect\thanks}
                                             \def\footnote{\protect\footnote}%
If you say, e.g., `\def\a1{...}', then you must always
put `1' after `\a', since control sequence names are
made up of letters only. The macro here has not been
followed by the required stuff, so I'm ignoring it.

)
Runaway argument?
\fi \if@stage@final \else \if@cop@home \ifonline \let \orig@psheadings \ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \__kernel_file_name_expand_loop:w.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.13 
     
I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing me
to read past where you wanted me to stop.
I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious,
you'd better type `E' or `X' now and fix your file.

)
! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 13.
<inserted text> 
                \fi 
<*> template.tex
                
The file ended while I was skipping conditional text.
This kind of error happens when you say `\if...' and forget
the matching `\fi'. I've inserted a `\fi'; this might work.

! Emergency stop.
<*> template.tex
                
*** (job aborted, no legal \end found)

 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 1646 strings out of 481252
 22785 string characters out of 5915888
 320674 words of memory out of 5000000
 18635 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 404299 words of font info for 29 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 14 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 82i,0n,89p,323b,126s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805).

Comment: We'd also like to see your compilation log of the minimal example that José mentioned. Note, that is the contents of the `.log` file, not the filtered output you cite in your question

Comment: You are using a non-standard class: we are going to need to know the exact version

Comment: I think that is a problem in regexpatch 0.2e which has been resolved in 0.2f, see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/578518/2388

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I've tried the MWE proposed in this discussion and I got the following error: ```Undefined control sequence. \regexpatchcmd{\hello}{Hi}{Hello}{}{}```. I don't know what I should do to get regexpatch 0.2f. Could you please give me more details? Many thanks for your help!

Comment: A current regexpatch is here https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/regexpatch. But I can't tell you if it works in your older system.

Comment: Thanks. However, I'm not really sure what I'm supposed to do with that... Sorry. I've got texlive-latex-extra which is up to date. I don't know how the LaTeX packages are downloaded and updated. Is it correct that the regexpatch version supplied by texlive-latex-extra is 0.2e? You suggest me to download a new version (0.2f) and to replace the older one, is that correct? Could you please tell me how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: debian tex systems are typically not up-to-date (you have texlive 2020, current is texlive 2021). Also the readme in the ctan link says how to unpack the sty from the ins + dtx. Then you only need to copy the new sty in the folder of your document and can try if it works. Don't replace the original, then you can always go back.

Comment: Many thanks. I'll try. Wouldn’t it be better to update the whole textlive?

Comment: I've tried and it works fine now! Many thanks! I've renamed old regexpatch.sty as regexpatch_old.sty in order to keep it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to replies in comments of the first post, here is the solution:

It is a problem in regexpatch 0.2e which has been resolved in 0.2f. This last version can be downloaded here: ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/regexpatch.